# macOS creating alias programmatically

Tags: macos, plist, alias, shortcut

I've ben fiddling around how to create an alias to a program with some arguments.

Tried `osascript` to tell Finder to create an alias in a folder to a plist, but that didn't work. It just made an alias to the plist.

My question is, with which command or how is it possible to create a shortcut to an executable with arguments, and that all programmatically, e.g. from Java with `Runtime.exec()`.

Comment: Not so clear. What do you means by alias? File system alias or command line ? Use automator to create an *application automaton* that call your app with args it needs.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Just like a Windows .lnk file. Calling an executable with custom arguments.